# Find cases where any value appears in another column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Simplified for the purposes of example...

I have a table, t1:

```
Reference  Ticket  TicketDate  Outcome  Source
        1       1  2017-01-01        0       A
        1       2  2017-01-02        0       A
        1       3  2017-01-03        1       A
        2       4  2017-01-01        0       A
        2       4  2017-01-01        0       B
        2       4  2017-01-01        0       C
        2       5  2017-01-02        0       B
        2       6  2017-01-03        1       B
        3       7  2017-01-01        0       A
        3       8  2017-01-02        0       A
        3       9  2017-01-03        1       B
```

What I want to do is categorise the outcomes by source where the latest outcome is 1 where it had been 0 prevoiusly...

For example:

```
with CTE as
(
select t1.*, dense_rank() over(partition by reference order by ticketdate desc) as rn
from t1
)
select c1.reference, c1.outcome, count(distinct c2.ticket) as now1was0
from CTE c1
left join CTE c2
on c1.reference = c2.reference
and c2.rn > c1.rn
and c2.outcome = 0
and c2.ticket <> c1.ticket
where c1.outcome = 1
group by reference, outcome
```

Which works fine, but now I want to split the count where the same source appears previously vs where it does not.

eg:

```
reference  outcome  now1was0same  now1was0different
        1        1             1                  0
        2        1             1                  0
        3        1             0                  1
```

If the source of the outcome = 1 exists in ANY of the previous Outcome = 0  rows for the reference, it needs to appear.

Can someone help my get from where I am to where I need to be?

*Edit*

It is possible that some references will have a subsequent outcome = 0, but I plan on ignoring these entirely, and will handle this in the cascade of CTEs that got me to this point

Comment: what if the previous row to the latest row with an outcome of 1 had an outcome of 1 (and the previous row to that had an outcome of 0)? E.g. if the outcome for the row with reference = 3 and ticket = 8 had an outcome of 1, would you still want  to appear in your output?

Comment: @Boneist In that case, that reference would appear in both. I hadn't even considered that scenario, but it's plausable.

Comment: And what if there are 1 outcome rows present, but no 0 rows, or vice-versa?

Comment: @Boneist I don't care about those at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example data only shows `outcome=1` for the latest entry; using this assumption you can do it all using analytic functions and get rid of the self-join:

```
SELECT reference,
       outcome,
       same_src AS now1was0same,
       all_src - same_src AS now1was0different
FROM   (
  SELECT reference,
         outcome,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY reference ORDER BY TicketDate DESC ) AS rn,
         COUNT( CASE outcome WHEN 0 THEN 1 END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY reference, source )
           AS same_src,
         COUNT( CASE outcome WHEN 0 THEN 1 END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY reference )
           AS all_src
  FROM   t1
)
WHERE rn = 1
AND   outcome = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you're after - again, it uses analytic functions to do the work:

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT 1 REFERENCE, 1 ticket, DATE '2017-01-01' ticketdate, 0 outcome, 'A' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 REFERENCE, 2 ticket, DATE '2017-01-02' ticketdate, 0 outcome, 'A' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 REFERENCE, 3 ticket, DATE '2017-01-03' ticketdate, 1 outcome, 'A' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 REFERENCE, 4 ticket, DATE '2017-01-01' ticketdate, 0 outcome, 'A' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 REFERENCE, 4 ticket, DATE '2017-01-01' ticketdate, 0 outcome, 'B' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 REFERENCE, 4 ticket, DATE '2017-01-01' ticketdate, 0 outcome, 'C' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 REFERENCE, 5 ticket, DATE '2017-01-02' ticketdate, 0 outcome, 'B' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 REFERENCE, 6 ticket, DATE '2017-01-03' ticketdate, 1 outcome, 'B' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 REFERENCE, 7 ticket, DATE '2017-01-01' ticketdate, 0 outcome, 'A' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 REFERENCE, 8 ticket, DATE '2017-01-02' ticketdate, 0 outcome, 'A' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 REFERENCE, 9 ticket, DATE '2017-01-03' ticketdate, 1 outcome, 'B' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 REFERENCE, 10 ticket, DATE '2017-01-01' ticketdate, 0 outcome, 'A' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 REFERENCE, 11 ticket, DATE '2017-01-02' ticketdate, 1 outcome, 'A' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 REFERENCE, 12 ticket, DATE '2017-01-03' ticketdate, 1 outcome, 'B' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 REFERENCE, 13 ticket, DATE '2017-01-01' ticketdate, 0 outcome, 'C' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 REFERENCE, 14 ticket, DATE '2017-01-02' ticketdate, 1 outcome, 'B' SOURCE FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 REFERENCE, 15 ticket, DATE '2017-01-03' ticketdate, 0 outcome, 'B' SOURCE FROM dual),
    res AS (SELECT REFERENCE,
                   ticket,
                   ticketdate,
                   outcome,
                   SOURCE,
                   CASE WHEN outcome = 1 THEN LAG(CASE WHEN outcome = 0 THEN 0 END IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY REFERENCE ORDER BY ticketdate) END prior_0_oc,
                   CASE WHEN outcome = 1 THEN LAG(CASE WHEN outcome = 0 THEN SOURCE END IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY REFERENCE ORDER BY ticketdate) END prior_0_src,
                   CASE WHEN outcome = 1 THEN LEAD(CASE WHEN outcome = 0 THEN 'Y' END IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY REFERENCE ORDER BY ticketdate) END next_0_present
            FROM   t1)
SELECT REFERENCE,
       outcome,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN prior_0_oc = 0 AND prior_0_src = SOURCE THEN 1 END) now1was0samesrc,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN prior_0_oc = 0 AND prior_0_src != SOURCE THEN 1 END) now1was0diffsrc
FROM res
WHERE outcome = 1
AND   next_0_present IS NULL
GROUP BY REFERENCE,
         outcome
ORDER BY REFERENCE;
```

and this produces:

```
 REFERENCE    OUTCOME NOW1WAS0SAMESRC NOW1WAS0DIFFSRC
---------- ---------- --------------- ---------------
         1          1               1               0
         2          1               1               0
         3          1               0               1
         4          1               1               1
```

This query finds (for outcome = 1 rows) the first previous row where the outcome is 0 and picks the outcome and source from it, then it finds if there is a subsequent row with a 0 outcome (so we can exclude those from the report - I think that's what you meant?).

Then it filters out all the 0 outcome rows and any outcome = 1 rows with following 0 outcome row(s) before doing a conditional counts to find the cases you're after.

Depending on how you want to display results that don't match either of the two scenarios you're checking for, you may wish to include a having clause in the final sql statement to exclude rows where the counts are both 0.

---

ETA:

If you want to count cases where the rows for a given reference flip between 0 and 1 more than once (i.e. 0, 0, 1, 0, 1) but still ignore references that end with a 0 outcome, then change:

```
                   CASE WHEN outcome = 1 THEN LEAD(CASE WHEN outcome = 0 THEN 'Y' END IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY REFERENCE ORDER BY ticketdate) END next_0_present
```

to:

```
               CASE WHEN outcome = 1 AND row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY REFERENCE, outcome ORDER BY ticketdate DESC) = 1
                           THEN LAG(CASE WHEN outcome = 0 THEN 'Y' END IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY REFERENCE ORDER BY ticketdate DESC) END next_0_present
```

Of course, if I've got the wrong end of the stick entirely on what you meant by:

> It is possible that some references will have a subsequent outcome = 0, but I plan on ignoring these entirely

and you just meant ignore the extra 0 rows, then of course you can just remove the next_0_present column from the query.